# What is Javascript Fetch (0) Doing

Tags: javascript

I'm modifying someone's search form php code and they are not available to question.

I think I've searched all the relevant php files, but I can't find out what the `javascript:fetch(0)` is actually running:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" 
       value="<?php _e('Filter', 'plan-vacation') ?>" 
       style="float:left;margin:14px 0pt 1em; position:relative;top:0.35em;" 
       onclick="javascript:fetch(0);return false;" />
```

The initial query to the database requests all the data elements (fname, lname, mname, bday, age), but only suppose to show fname, lname, mname in an HTTP table and it does.

Example--first render of page:

```
Col 1   Col 2  Col 3
Bob     Lewis  S.
Tom     Lewis  R.
Sue     Lewis  V.
Tim     Thomas L.
```

But, when I select lname "lewis", click the search form the headings of the table stay the same (great!), I get only the lname records with lewis (great!), but the table rows have many more data elements in the (i.e., bday, age, etc.) new table on the HTTP page.  I'm stumped.

```
Col 1   Col 2  Col 3
Bob     Lewis  S.    31 Jan 2002  14
Tom     Lewis  R.    31 Dec 2001  13
Sue     Lewis  V.    15 Mar 2000  16
```

Why is it doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the `fetch` and the rest of the question are related?

Comment: you can read the spec at https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/ or the MDN doc at  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: @Supersharp: I doubt it's that `fetch`, given the argument. More likely something defined in the script.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ok so the question would need a supplement of information. Anyway it made me discover this interesting JS feature :-)

Comment: @Supersharp: Browser feature, not JS. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder a Web feature usable in a non-browser context, and made accessible through a JS API :-?